# Apache Camel Multicast notifyBuilder fails

Tags: apache-camel

Of some reason, QUEUE_A does not ALWAYS has 1 exchanges - sometimes it has 0, unless I add a Thread.sleep(100) to the test. I guess whenCompleted/whenDone isn't completely done when it actually says it's done. How can I verify that it is completely done?

```
multicast().parallelProcessing().to(QUEUE_A, QUEUE_B, QUEUE_C, QUEUE_D)
```

And testing with:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    NotifyBuilder notify = new NotifyBuilder(context)
            .from(QUEUE_INCOMING)
            .whenCompleted(1)
            .create();
    template.sendBody(QUEUE_INCOMING, streamToString(loadResourceAsStream("/data/TestData.xml")));

    boolean matches = notify.matches(4, SECONDS);
    assertTrue("Notify failed", matches);
    Thread.sleep(100); //Without this, it fails 

    verifyEndpoints(1, context, QUEUE_A, QUEUE_B, QUEUE_C, QUEUE_D);
}

public static void verifyEndpoints(int expectedSize, ModelCamelContext context, String... endpoints) {
    for (String endpoint : endpoints) {
        BrowsableEndpoint be = context.getEndpoint(endpoint, BrowsableEndpoint.class);
        assertThat(String.format("Endpoint exchanges '%s' has wrong size", endpoint), be.getExchanges(), hasSize(expectedSize));
    }
}
```

And the endpoint bean, using ActiveMQ when testing, but is going to use WebSphere MQ in prod:

```
<bean id="wmq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
      <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false" />
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: what kind of endpoints are QUEUE_A, ... ?

Comment: They are "wmq:queues:<queuename>". I added wmq bean setting to the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you browse a WMQ asap after sending a message to it, and therefore depending on broker implementation and timing etc, you may not see the very last messages, when using the JMS browsing api.

And hence why it seems to fix when you wait a bit with the sleep.

Comment: What would be a better solution than sleep?

Comment: I actually have the same problem when having a NotifyBuilder which waits for a route with a wiretap. It is done when the wiretap returns completed, but the whole routing is not done yet.
In this case I can add wereSentTo(q), to the queue I'm waiting for.

But in the multicast version, I used multiple wereSentTo() for each multicast queue, but that didn't work. I actually didn't get .whenDone(1).wereSentTo(QUEUE_A).wereSentTo(QUEUE_B).create() to work. Might be a bug?